# winform change BackgroundImage property of a button on hover

Tags: c#, winforms, button, background-image

I want to change the `backgroundImage` property of a button on hover like below :

```
    private void btnGetHardwareID_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnGetHardwareID.BackgroundImage = (System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources._11949847771696668271pill_button_green_benji__01_svg_med);
        btnGetHardwareID.Refresh();
    }

    private void btnGetHardwareID_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnGetHardwareID.BackgroundImage = (System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources._11949847771793996117pill_button_purple_benji_01_svg_med);
        btnGetHardwareID.Refresh();
    }
```

and the peroperties of btnGetHardwareID are like below :

```
    // btnGetHardwareID
    // 
    this.btnGetHardwareID.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
    this.btnGetHardwareID.BackgroundImage = global::Travian.Properties.Resources._11949847771793996117pill_button_purple_benji_01_svg_med;
    this.btnGetHardwareID.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
    this.btnGetHardwareID.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
    this.btnGetHardwareID.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
    this.btnGetHardwareID.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Cambria", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
    this.btnGetHardwareID.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    this.btnGetHardwareID.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(31, 53);
    this.btnGetHardwareID.Name = "btnGetHardwareID";
    this.btnGetHardwareID.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(160, 40);
    this.btnGetHardwareID.TabIndex = 25;
    this.btnGetHardwareID.Text = "Get My Hardware-ID";
    this.btnGetHardwareID.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
    this.btnGetHardwareID.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnGetHardwareID_Click);
    this.btnGetHardwareID.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.btnGetHardwareID_MouseDown);
    this.btnGetHardwareID.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.btnGetHardwareID_MouseEnter);
    this.btnGetHardwareID.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.btnGetHardwareID_MouseLeave);
    this.btnGetHardwareID.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.btnGetHardwareID_MouseUp);
```

now the problem is that backgroundImage on MouseEnter is like this :
[image: Mouse Enter]

and on MouseLeave is like this :

[image: Mouse Leave]

what is that Grayed BackColor around green button and how can i remove that?

**EDIT**
original images are like below :

[image: red button - original - png format]

[image: green button - original - png format]

and that MainForm's background :

[image: main form - background-image]

thanks in advance

Comment: i removed those MouseLeave and MouseEnter events / but still have that grayed area on Hover!

Comment: You probably forgot to make the image transparent in those corners.

Comment: @Hans Passant those images are in png format and i checked their Transparent using with photoshop and there is no problem about them!

Comment: I test your code with a png image it's work fine,try another png

Comment: Hard to debug a screenshot, we don't know anything about the container control either.  Post a minimum repro project on a file sharing service.

Comment: change btnGetHardwareID.Refresh(); to btnGetHardwareID.Invalidate();  If that does not work then you may need to create a mask for the image.

Comment: would you please help me to create that mask!

Comment: @MoonLight See my post, it was much simpler then creating the mask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution you are looking for is below. Set the FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor to transparent.

```
this.btnGetHardwareID.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
```